# Running Nant gives "SDK for the 'net-2.0' framework is not available or not configured" even AFTER sdk 2.0 installed

Tags: .net, sdk, nant

I know there are a few questions on this issue out there, but none of the answers have solved it for me.

I get "The SDK for the 'net-2.0' framework is not available or not configured" error when I try ty run NAnt 0.92, even though I have installed the .NET SDK v2.0; no key in register with "sdkInstallRoot".

When I installed the SDK 2.0 I noticed it was being installed under the "Visual Studio 8" folder, and I think that's the source of the problem. How do I fix that, so that the installation is under the .NET SDK folder? Running the setup doesn't show me any option to change the directory.

Any ideas on how to fix the .NET SDK directory in order to get NAnt working?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my issue:

http://www.donnfelker.com/nant-sdkinstallroot-has-not-been-set/

I had a similar issue with 4.5 framework. I have a 64 bit machine but .net is installed as 32 bit. I replaced the entry for sdkInstallRoot in nant.exe.config. Basically I replaced:

```
<locatesdk property="sdkInstallRoot" minwinsdkver="v7.0A" minnetfxver="4.0" maxnetfxver="4.0.99999" failonerror="false" />
```

with this:

```
<readregistry
                            property="sdkInstallRoot"
                            key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools\InstallationFolder"
                            hive="LocalMachine"
                            failonerror="false" />
```